# Is there any reason why I sometimes hear masU and desU?

Tags: pronunciation

I don't hear real life japanese that often, (I watch some podcasts and stuff) but when listening to anime, I hear ます and です said very often with the u being fully pronounced. I was wondering, is this just an anime thing? Do certain types of people do this? Age group? Gender? Or is it just people that like to do it do it?
ありがとうございます

Comment: Search "devoicing" or in Japanese "無声化"

Comment: ^ But the question is why/when the U is pronounced, i.e. devoicing/無声化 **doesn't** occur, no?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Devoicing) does mention difference by gender and region.

Comment: @Chocolate It's easier to search for devoicing. The info's in the same place

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/why-is-好すき-pronounced-with-a-voiceless-almost-silent-u-but-隙すき-is-not?rq=1